# Battery Management in Ubuntu

Tags: power-management, battery

How can I change the Battery Management settings in my Laptop? I used to have a Windows installed and in that, the battery management program (for the sake of battery health) had the charging limited to 60%. Now I'm on Ubuntu and what should I do to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at tp_smapi, although the tool is made for thinkpads I've heard stories about people being able to use it on other brands as well. Here is some extra info on thinkwiki: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi

Comment: `tp_smapi` is only for certain ThinkPad laptops. How do you know this applies to the machine of the OP?

Comment: _"although the tool is made for thinkpads I've heard stories about people being able to use it on other brands as well."_ I never implied that this is works on this laptop model. I just suggested because it **might** work.

Answer (score 0):

Charging limits depend upon your vendor.But if you would like to save power and prevent overheating problems,you could install a panel app called CPUfreq.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Now,all you have to do is type

```
indicator-cpufreq
```

in the terminal to launch it for the first time.Once started,choose the powersave option.